# Calculation of thermal equivalent short-time current

Tags: voltage, short-circuit, circuit-breaker, busbar

Regarding checking the thermal resistance of switchgear "Ith", To make the comparison, one can compare the permanent short-circuit current "Ik" calculated by the ETAP software and the switchgear thermal resistance given by the manufacturer. My concern is that the thermal resistance is the short time current for 1 or 3 s and "Ik" calculated by etap software is the PERMANENT short circuit current, is the comparison valid?

Comment: By "permanent", do you mean continuous? I'd say just about any condition most parts can handle for three seconds (a *very* long time in this context), they can also handle continuously.